# Why as.numeric("1221008815753031681") returns 1221008815753031680?

Tags: r

This doesn't require an extensive explanation. Why

```
as.numeric("1221008815753031681")
```

returns

> [1] 1221008815753031680

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: If you look at `.Machine$integer.max`, you'll see that it's likely `2147483647` (10 digits). This is the largest *strict integer* that R can store in 32-bit integers (64-bit ints are a long-sought-after feature, supported by the `bit64` package but not universally used/supported by other packages). While this 32-bit int here is only 10 digits, your number is 19 digits, clearly well outside of what R can use. For this, R defaults to giving you *a number*, which in this case is technically a `numeric` (float/double). When numbers get large, there can be rounding errors, ergo the link above.

Comment: the question I've tagged as a duplicate goes in the opposite direction, but the reasoning (and solutions) are applicable in this case as well.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, that's a far better and informative dupe question